# Swift 2 - Recall object inside a Multidimensional NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, swift2

How can I recall the objects inside a Multidimensional NSMutableArray?

```
var userVideoNames2: NSMutableArray = [[]]

    userVideoNames2 = [
                ["aaa-0", "bob-0", "ccc-0", "ddd-0"],
                ["aaa-1", "bob-1", "ccc-1", "ddd-1"],
                ["aaa-2", "bob-2", "ccc-2", "ddd-2"],
                ["aaa-3", "bob-3", "ccc-3", "ddd-3"],
                ["aaa-4", "bob-4", "ccc-4", "ddd-4"]
            ]

            print(userVideoNames2[3][0]) // aaa-3  ???
            print(userVideoNames2[1][2]) // ccc-1  ???
```

Comment: Why are you using NSMutableArray at all? That's a pretty silly thing to do with Swift.

Comment: What is the error message? What issue are you having? What is not working with your code?

Comment: I use NSMutable Array because the array is generated and it can change

Comment: @SNos: `var` allows a Swift array to "change" - you can re-generate the array and then assign it to `userVideoNames2`. And I've just run your code in a Playground and it works fine (even though you should be using a Swift Array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use NSMutableArray. Swift arrays *are* mutable. Declare `userVideoNames2` as a `[[String]]` and all will be well.

```
var userVideoNames2 = [[String]]()
```

Comment: I use NSMutable Array because the array is generated and it can change

Comment: I don't see your point. As I said, a Swift array is mutable. Please just try doing what I said; you will see that your `print` statements work. I've answered the question.

Comment: ok sorry.. and how I recall the object?    print(userVideoNames2[3[2]])

Comment: Exactly as you were doing it in your question. Just change what I said to change in the code you gave, and run that code!